# How do I import this Ant Design TypeScript interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ant-design-pro

I have this TypeScript error:

> Type 'xyz' is not assignable to type 'TableComponents'.

So I need to cast my type as TableComponents. But this interface is not available when I try to import it using:

```js
import { TableComponents } from 'antd/lib/table/interface';
```

The interface is [listed here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/1c85bb3b6231a01c53c53204846a03c4cfdf41f9/components/table/Table.tsx) as being part of the library.

How do I import it to my React project?

Comment: Which antd version do you use?

Comment: Hi @zerocewl - 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You might look at an outdated version of `interface.tsx`.

[This](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/table/interface.tsx) is the version on master and there is no `TableComponents`.

The antd branch should fit the lib version you use.

Comment: Ok thanks, yes the interface is not there, but then why is Typescript asking for it?

Comment: can you post a minimal reproduceable example as stackblitz or codesanbox?